# Best Practice For Fuzzy Search Combined With Phrase Queries

Tags: search, full-text-search

I am interested in best practices on how to handle phrase queries with possible spelling errors.
Are there any objectives on when to use only a part of the query phrase or how
many words of the phrase should rather be corrected before skipping them?
Does anyone know how e.g. Google or Amazon deals with these issues?
Best regards
Markus